# Like button in MVC using 'Ajax.Beginform()' not able to display total likes on page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, viewbag, ajax.beginform

I am beginner in MVC and Ajax development and want a like button in my web, which should work like this: if the user clicks on it total likes will be incremented by `1` and if the user clicks it again (dislike) then it will decremented by `1`. What I have done so far is this:

Here's the Model:

```
public class Like
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Controller:
Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Like(int Id, Like like)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                like.Video = storeDB.Videos.Find(Id);
                like.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

                var userlike = storeDB.Likes.Where(l => l.UserId == like.UserId && l.VideoID == Id);

                if (userlike.Count() == 0)
                {
                    storeDB.Likes.Add(like);
                    storeDB.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (userlike.Count() == 1)
                {
                    var likeDel = storeDB.Likes.FirstOrDefault(l => l.UserId == like.UserId && l.VideoID == Id);
                    storeDB.Likes.Remove(likeDel);
                    storeDB.SaveChanges();
                }
                List<Like> videoLikes = storeDB.Likes.Where(v => v.VideoID == Id).ToList();
                int nooflikes = videoLikes.Count();
                ViewBag.noLikes = nooflikes;
                return Json(ViewBag.noLikes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Login to like this video";
                return PartialView("Like", ViewBag.noLikes);
            }
```

This is the Get method of Like:

```
public ActionResult Like(int id)
    {
        List<Like> videoLikes = storeDB.Likes.Where(v => v.VideoID == id).ToList();
        int nooflikes = videoLikes.Count();
        ViewBag.noLikes = nooflikes;
        return Json(ViewBag.noLikes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and I have created a Partial View for this:

```
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('@ViewBag.Message');
        });

    </script>
}
//to display total likes
        <input type="text" id="likes" name="likes" value='@ViewBag.noLikes' readonly="readonly" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; width:20px"  /><span style="color:black">likes</span>
```

and this is the main view in which I am using Ajax.BeginForm()

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Like", "VOD", new { Id = Model.Id },
             new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "likecount"
            }))
                        {

                            <button type="submit" id="like" value="Like" class=" btn btn-primary btn-xs"> Like &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                        }
                        <span id="likecount">
                            @Html.Partial("Like", new Models.Like())
                        </span>
```

Now the issue is that when the page is first loaded it is not displaying total likes, and when I click on like button it returns `1` and when I click like button again it returns `0` but when I refresh the page or when I post back to another page total likes again disappear.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing so much code you can do above functionality in simple way.
You will required following to do so,

2 Action Methods,
 1. Increment Like Count.
 2. Decrease Like Count.

2 Buttons on web page 
 1. Like Button (Initially visible)
 2. DisLike Button (Initially Invisible)

you can create a ajax request on both buttons something like bellow,

```
$("#btnLike").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Controller/LikeAction",
                data: { /* Your Data */ };
                success: function (result) {
                   // Hide Like Button & Show Dislike Button
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error = " + error);
                }
            });
});
```

Same way you can create ajax request for dislike button also. You just need to hide and show buttons.

Comment: ok, then in data:{ /* */ } what should i pass? I mean after clicking on Like button I want the value to be incremented.

Comment: You can send data whatever you require to increment Like Count. eg. UserId, Id